# Weird graphical text editor glitch in a dual monitor setup on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, text-editors, computing-environment

My dearest superusers,

I have a very weird graphics 'glitch' for certain IDE's or editors, like TexStudio and Spyder. It happens that certain lines or words overlap with each other, and sometimes certain lines have different fontsizes even (not shown in next image)

Screenshot for one example of *overlapping* words:
[image: See screenshot for one example of *overlapping* words]

It happens usually in my secondary monitor (LG Flatron E2350V), but if I remember correctly, it had appeared on my primary as well. My primary is just the one of my laptop (HP Pavilion - 14-al125nd). What I have noticed (from what I remember) is:

- When the problem appeared in Spyder in primary monitor, it was
  sometimes solved by saving the python file
- When the problem appeard in Spyder in secondary monitor, it was
  sometimes solved by maximizing the window.
- And at times none of the above methods worked for no monitor.
- When I drag one of the text environments (texStudio or Spyder) from monitor 1 to monitor 2, the text transitions into the glitched version.
- Also,some IDEs like Matlab, never experienced this problem. (And till now, I have never seen the problem elsewhere
- As far as I know, these two programs are the only ones where the glitch appeared.
- Lately, the problem does not appear in first monitor, but it still does in second one.

This suggests that the problem is time-varying and possibly also varies in its characteristcs.

To solve the problem, I've tried to:

- update to latests graphics drivers, both my integraded Intel card (HD
  Graphics 620), as well as my dedicated Nvdia GeFore 940MX card.
- Otherwise I've tried to search online but frankly, I do not really
  know the right search terms to find the same problem. Therefore I
  hope to find some answers or suggestions on this site!

Just to be clear, my question is **what causes and/or what can potentially solve the problem?**
Of course I do not know what information could be used/required to answer this question, so if there are any questions of additional details that I did not mention, please ask.

---

*Sidenote: I am not sure whether my tags are correct either. Feedback is appreciated.*

Comment: The IDE might not render the font properly.

Comment: Is that a logical deduction from the fact that it happens in different IDEs, and for one IDE it happens in one screen but it does not in another? I say no.

Comment: Is the display scaling set more than 100%?

Comment: That might be it actually, I changed it to 100% and I qm not seeing this problem anymore currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your display scaling of of all screens to 100%. To do this:

1. Right-click on the desktop
2. Click on *Display settings*
3. Change the display scaling to *100%* for each screen.

Comment: I think this is correct as I dont see the problem occur anymore.